# How to ignore certain characters in an input stream?

Tags: c++

I need to take input from the user which gives me 3 colors for red, green and blue, and prints it out in its' respective color.

The input needs to be in the form (255,255,255) with numbers that can range from 1 to 3 digits in between each comma. I would like to store each integer in _red, _green, and _blue respectively, whilst ignoring the parenthesis and commas.

```
#include "color.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

Color::Color(): _reset{true}{

}

Color::Color(int red, int green, int blue): _red{red}, _green{green}, _blue{blue}, _reset{false}{

}

std::string Color::to_string() const{
    return "(" + std::to_string(_red) + ","  + std::to_string(_green) + "," + std::to_string(_blue) + ")";
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ost, const Color& color){
    if(color._reset==false){
        ost << "\033[38;2;" << std::to_string(color._red) << ";" << std::to_string(color._green) << ";" << std::to_string(color._blue) << "m";
    }else{
        ost << "\033[0m\n";
    }
    return ost;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& ist, Color& color){
    ist.ignore(1,'(');
    ist >> color._red;
    ist.ignore(1,',');
    ist >> color._green;
    ist.ignore(1,',');
    ist >> color._blue;
    ist.ignore(1,')');
}
```

The problem in question is inside the operator>> overload. Why doesn't this implementation work as expected?

Comment: I'd consider getline, then parse it. You may need to worry about whitespace, too. But this way you can unit test your parsing function without having to do actual IO

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your `operator >>` overload needs to return the stream since it has changed inside the implementation.

The code below appears to work fine here:
I tested with (1,2,3), (0,255,0), (255,255,255), (127,0,1) ...

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Color {
    int r, g, b;

    std::string to_string() const;
};

std::string
Color::to_string() const
{
    return
        "{" + std::to_string(r) +
        "," + std::to_string(g) +
        "," + std::to_string(b) + "}";
}

std::istream&
operator>>(std::istream& ist, Color& color)
{
    ist.ignore(1,'(');
    ist >> color.r;
    ist.ignore(1,',');
    ist >> color.g;
    ist.ignore(1,',');
    ist >> color.b;
    ist.ignore(1,')');
    return ist;
}

int main()
{
    Color color;
    std::cout << "Insert color: ";
    std::cin >> color;
    std::cout << color.to_string() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Since you won't share the rest of the code (the definition of the `Color` class/structure), here is something that you can do to verify that the `operator >>` is working correctly:

Just print the values right after you read them!

```
std::istream&
operator>>(std::istream& ist, Color& color)
{
    ist.ignore(1,'(');
    ist >> color.r;
    ist.ignore(1,',');
    ist >> color.g;
    ist.ignore(1,',');
    ist >> color.b;
    ist.ignore(1,')');
    std::cout << r << " " << g << " " << b << std::endl;
    return ist;
}
```

It appears that somewhere else in your code the values of the member variables are being changed.

Comment: For some reason, this still doesn't work for me. I used the input (255,0,0), and I get `1196399479;32741m(0,-1196399479,32741:-861405333)` in the output.

Comment: Did you use exactly the code I posted, or did you changed yours? Also, what environment are you using? GCC, MSVC? x32, x64?

Comment: I don't know the class/struct definition of "Color" neither the purpose of "reset" that you are using. But it is working perfectly fine on the simple snippet I provided.

Comment: I changed my code, I just added `return ist;` after the last ignore. I'm using g++17.

Comment: The `operator >>` is now correct then. The problem should be somewhere else in the code. Is there any other thing happening to the instance before you output it?
Please take a moment and test the snippet I provided so we can discard any environment-related problems.

Comment: Your snippet worked! [This is what my main function looks like.](https://pastebin.com/f6FLX0Wn) (You can ignore the less_than function.)